# How do i throw HttpResponseException(NotFound) using AspNetCore

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I had method written in `.Net 4.5`
It is very simple. It either `returns Student entity or throw NOT FOUND exception.`

I am struggling to `port it into .NET Core 2.0.`
As per my understanding, `.net core` recommend to to return `IActionResult`so , i can simply return `NotFound().`

> However, i am not sure how do i throw an not HttpResponseException (Not Found) exception .

Method:

```
public Student Get(Guid id)
{
    Student student = _studentSvc.Get(id);
    if (student != null)
        return student;
    else
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
}
```

Attempt:

```
public Student Get(Guid id)
{
    Student student = _svc.Get(id);
    if (student != null)
        return student;
    else
        return NotFound();
}
```

And if i try like following, then this line `return student` complains that can't implicitly convert student into `...Mvc.IActionResult` something

```
public IActionResult Get(Guid id)
{
    Student student = _svc.Get(id);
    if (student != null)
        return student;
    else
        return NotFound();
}
```

But it gives error can not convert NotFoundResult to Student !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return IActionResult as you mentioned.

```
public IActionResult Get(Guid id)
{
    Student student = _svc.Get(id);
    if (student != null)
    {
        return Ok(student);
    }
    return NotFound();
}
```

Comment: if i return IActionResult then this line return student fails saying can't implicitly convert student to ActionResult;

Comment: Yes exactly that what i come up in the end. Howeever, what if you don't want to return anything to client but still want to throw NotFoundException. How would you do that?

Comment: Is the correct approach after the edit, you need to return `'Ok(student)` or `Content(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, student)`

Comment: @simbada, you can still throw an exception, if that is what you want to do, it will do the same it has always done.  But remember exceptions are more expensive

Comment: Thanks for your help. I belive IActionResult is the future. Returning HttpResponseMessage is an old thing and not recommeded anymore.